# является ли int неизменяемым типом в python?

Tags: python, память, int

```py
a = 100000
old_id = id(a)
a = a + 1
print(id(a) == old_id)
```

Вывод

```
False
```

почему при изменении переменой `а` создается новый объект? значит ли это, что целочисленный тип неизменяем?

Comment: **Матвей**, вместо картинки, пожалуйста, напишите текст программы буквами

Comment: 1) Потому, что в Python нет переменных, как таковых. Это просто имена. Почитайте, например, первую главу учебника Чернышева "Основы программирования на Python". 2) Непонятен вывод. Он не связан с пунктом 1. Типы в Python очень легко меняются. Это же язык с динамической типизацией.

Answer (score 1):

С одной стороны да, числовые типы такие как `int` действительно **иммутабельны** - объекты этого типа не изменяются, каждый новый объект, получающийся в результате вычислений - это действительно новый объект. Но есть небольшой нюанс, связанный с **интернированием** - некоторая часть объектов небольших целых чисел создаётся питоном заранее и при создании очередного объекта с таким значением новый объект не создаётся, а берётся готовый.

```py
def get_ids(x):
    ids = []
    ids.append(id(x))
    x += 1
    ids.append(id(x))
    x -= 1
    ids.append(id(x))
    return ids

ids10000 = get_ids(10000)
print(ids10000, len(set(ids10000)))

ids100 = get_ids(100)
print(ids100, len(set(ids100)))
```

Примерный вывод:

```
[139946014475600, 139946014475984, 139946014476336] 3
[94339239358176, 94339239358208, 94339239358176] 2
```

`10000`, `10000`+`1` => `10001` и `10001`-`1` => `10000` - это **3** разных объекта.
При этом `100`, `100`+`1` => `101` и `101`-`1` => `100` - это **2** разных объекта, потому что изначальное `100` и конечное `100`, полученное через вычисления - это **один** объект. Такая вот особенность реализации, связанная с оптимизацией (создавать новые объекты дорого).

Answer (score 1):

Все верно, `int` тип не изменяемый.

Что происходит в данном случае? Вы создаете объект типа `int` и имя `a` хранит ссылку на этот объект. Именно ссылку.

Когда вы вызываете `a = a + 1`, то сначала исполняется операция сложение по правую сторону от знака равно, следом создается новый объект под тем же именем `a` и новая ссылка на этот объект. А старое значение, поскольку больше нет ссылки на этот объект уничтожается. В итоге у вас новый объект и новая ссылка на него, которая хранится под старым именем